# How to dynamically know if pySpark DF has a null/empty value for given columns?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I have to check if incoming data is having any `null` or `""` or `"    "` value or not. The column for which I have to check is not fixed. I am reading from a config where the column name is stored for different files with permissible null-ability.

```
+----------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| FileName |     Nullable     |                  Columns                   |
+----------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| Sales    | Address2,Phone2  | OrderID,Address1,Address2,Phone1,Phone2    |
| Invoice  | Bank,OfcAddress  | InvoiceNo,InvoiceID,Amount,Bank,OfcAddress |
+----------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

So for each data/file I have to see which field shouldn't contain `null`. On basis of that process/error out the file. Is there any pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The table structure you’re showing makes me believe you have read the file containing these job details as a Spark DataFrame. You probably shouldn’t, as it’s very likely not big data. If you have it as a Spark DataFrame, `collect` it to the driver, so that you can create separate Spark jobs for each file.

Then, each job is fairly straightforward: you have a certain file location from which you must read. That info is captured by the `FileName`, I presume. Now, I will also presume the file format for each of these files is identical. If not, you’ll have to add meta data indicating the file format. For now, I assume it’s CSV.

Next, you must determine the subset of columns that needs to be checked for the presence of nulls. That’s easy: given that you have a list of all columns in the DataFrame (which could’ve been derived from the DataFrame generated by the previous step (the loading)) and a list of all columns that can contain nulls, the list of columns that can’t contain nulls is simply the difference between these two.

Finally, you `agg`regate over the DataFrame the number of nulls within each of these columns. As this is a DataFrame aggregate, there’s only one row in the result set, so you can take `head` to bring it to the driver. Cast is to a dict for easier access to the attributes.

I’ve added a function, `summarize_positive_counts`, that returns the columns where there was at least one null record found, thereby invalidating the claim in the original table.

```py
df.show(truncate=False)
# +--------+---------------+------------------------------------------+
# |FileName|Nullable       |Columns                                   |
# +--------+---------------+------------------------------------------+
# |Sales   |Address2,Phone2|OrderID,Address1,Address2,Phone1,Phone2   |
# |Invoice |Bank,OfcAddress|InvoiceNo,InvoiceID,Amount,Bank,OfcAddress|
# +--------+---------------+------------------------------------------+

jobs = df.collect()  # bring it to the driver, to create new Spark jobs from its 

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum as spark_sum


def report_null_counts(frame, job):
    cols_to_verify_not_null = (set(job.Columns.split(","))
                               .difference(job.Nullable.split(",")))
    null_counts = frame.agg(*(spark_sum(col(_).isNull().cast("int")).alias(_)
                              for _ in cols_to_verify_not_null))
    return null_counts.head().asDict()


def summarize_positive_counts(filename, null_counts):
    return {filename: [colname for colname, nbr_of_nulls in null_counts.items()
                       if nbr_of_nulls > 0]}


for job in jobs:  # embarassingly parallellizable
    frame = spark.read.csv(job.FileName, header=True)
    null_counts = report_null_counts(frame, job)
    print(summarize_positive_counts(job.FileName, null_counts))
```